# React JS fetch post get error object object error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, jsx, fetch-api

Post api work postman correctly but Rect JS post not working. Console get this error "POST https://localhost:5001/api/request 400 (Bad Request)" . I tried several time change fetch to axio post but It is not work. I am beginner to react js. I don't know what to do this. I attached my code to this. please help me this is very important.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { variables } from "../../Variables";


const  Request =() =>{
const [request_user_name, set_request_user_name] = useState('')
const [request_first_name, set_request_first_name] = useState('')
const [request_gender, set_request_gender] = useState('')
const [request_last_name, set_request_last_name] = useState('')
const [request_phone, set_request_phone] = useState('')
const [request_email, set_request_email] = useState('')
const [request_spotify, set_request_spotify] = useState('')
const [request_itunes, set_request_itunes] = useState('')
const [request_youtube, set_request_youtube] = useState('')
const [request_facebook, set_request_facebook] = useState('')
const [request_instagram, set_request_instagram] = useState('')

const handleUsername = (e)=>{
    set_request_user_name(e.target.value)
}
const handleFirstname = (e)=>{
    set_request_first_name(e.target.value)
}
const handleLastname = (e)=>{
    set_request_last_name(e.target.value)
}
const handlePhone = (e)=>{
    set_request_phone(e.target.value)
}
const handleEmail = (e)=>{
    set_request_email(e.target.value)
}
const handleSpotify = (e)=>{
    set_request_spotify(e.target.value)
}
const handlgender = (e)=>{
    set_request_gender(e.target.value)
}
const handleitunes = (e)=>{
    set_request_itunes(e.target.value)
}

const handleYoutube = (e)=>{
    set_request_youtube(e.target.value)
}
const handleFacebook = (e)=>{
    set_request_facebook(e.target.value)
}
const handleInstagram = (e)=>{
    set_request_instagram(e.target.value)
}

function requestClick(){
    console.log(request_user_name);
      fetch(variables.API_URL+'request',{
       method:'POST',
       headers:{
          'Accept':'application/json',
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
      },
       body:JSON.stringify({
          request_user_name:request_user_name,
          request_first_name:request_first_name,
          request_last_name:request_last_name,
          request_gender:request_gender,
          request_phone:request_phone,
          request_email:request_email,
          request_spotify:request_spotify,
          request_itunes:request_itunes,
          request_youtube:request_youtube,
          request_facebook:request_facebook,
          request_instagram:request_instagram

  })
     })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then((result)=>{
        alert(result)
        window.location.reload(false);
    },(error)=>{
        alert('Failed');
    })
}

    return(
            <div>
                <center>
                    <h1>Connect with us</h1>
                    <hr/>
                    <h3>Reqest for Account !</h3>
                    <p></p>
                    <div className="container">
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <div className="row">
                            <style>{"\ .rr{\ float:left;\ }\ "} </style>
                            <style>{"\ .bb{\ float:right;\ }\ "} </style>
                            <style>{"\ .txt{\ height:40px; \ }\ "} </style>
                            <div className="col">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label className="form-label rr d-flex"> Username</label>
                                    <div className="input-group input-group-lg">
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control txt" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Username"
                                        value={request_user_name}
                                        onChange={handleUsername}/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label className="form-label rr d-flex"> First Name</label>
                                    <div className="input-group input-group-lg">
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control txt" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Username"
                                        value={request_first_name}
                                        onChange={handleFirstname}/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label className="form-label rr d-flex"> Last Name</label>
                                    <div className="input-group input-group-lg">
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control txt" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Username"
                                        value={request_last_name}
                                        onChange={handleLastname}/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <style>{"\ .rr{\ float:left;\ }\ "} </style>
                            <style>{"\ .bb{\ float:right;\ }\ "} </style>
                            <style>{"\ .txt{\ height:40px; \ }\ "} </style>
                            <div className="col">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label className="form-label rr d-flex"> Gender</label>
                                    <div className="input-group input-group-lg">
                                    <div class="form-check ">
                                        <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1" checked
                                        value="1"
                                        onChange={handlgender}/>
                                        <label className="form-check-label ml-3" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                                            Male
                                        </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                        <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault2" 
                                        value="1"
                                        onChange={handlgender}/>
                                        <label className="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
                                            Female
                                        </label>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                            <label className="form-label rr d-flex"> Phone Number</label>
                                    <div className="input-group input-group-lg">
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control txt" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Username"
                                        value={request_phone}
                                        onChange={handlePhone}/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label className="form-label rr d-flex"> Email</label>
                                    <div className="input-group input-group-lg">
                                        <input type="email" className="form-control txt" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Username"
                                        value={request_email}
                                        onChange={handleEmail}/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <style>{"\ .rr{\ float:left;\ }\ "} </style>
                            <style>{"\ .bb{\ float:right;\ }\ "} </style>
                            <style>{"\ .txt{\ height:40px; \ }\ "} </style>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <style>{"\ .rr{\ float:left;\ }\ "} </style>
                            <style>{"\ .bb{\ float:right;\ }\ "} </style>
                            <style>{"\ .txt{\ height:40px; \ }\ "} </style>
                            <div className="col">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label className="form-label rr d-flex"> Spotify</label>
                                    <div className="input-group input-group-lg">
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control txt" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Username"
                                        value={request_spotify}
                                        onChange={handleSpotify} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label className="form-label rr d-flex"> itunes</label>
                                    <div className="input-group input-group-lg">
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control txt" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Username"
                                        value={request_itunes}
                                        onChange={handleitunes}/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label className="form-label rr d-flex"> Youtube</label>
                                    <div className="input-group input-group-lg">
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control txt" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Username"
                                        value={request_youtube}
                                        onChange={handleYoutube}/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <style>{"\ .rr{\ float:left;\ }\ "} </style>
                            <style>{"\ .bb{\ float:right;\ }\ "} </style>
                            <style>{"\ .txt{\ height:40px; \ }\ "} </style>
                            <div className="col-2">
                                </div>
                            <div className="col">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label className="form-label rr d-flex"> Facebook</label>
                                    <div className="input-group input-group-lg">
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control txt" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Username"
                                        value={request_facebook}
                                        onChange={handleFacebook}/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                    <label className="form-label rr d-flex"> Instagram</label>
                                    <div className="input-group input-group-lg">
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control txt" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Username"
                                        value={request_instagram}
                                        onChange={handleInstagram}/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-2">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                           <div className="raw">
                           <style>{"\ .bb{\ float:right;\ }\ "} </style>
                               <div className="col-5">

                               </div>
                               <div className="col-1">
                               <button type="button" className="btn btn-success bb"
                                    onClick={requestClick}  >Request</button>
                               </div>
                               <div className="col-5">
                                   
                               </div>
                           </div>

                      
                   
                    </div>
                   
                </center>
            </div>
    )
}


export default Request
```

Comment: if you build your api what does it expect? bad request could mean you are not sending the right data.

Comment: Alert box display object object error, sending data is right same as the postman details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, I missed the sending parameters in the radio button value. Then I change the code and now It is work.